# 422 and Can't verify CSRF token authenticity on Rails and Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, devise

I am using Rails and Devise on passenger and nginx. By moving to production on my VPS, I can't the app to log in, it displays:

> The change you wanted was rejected.
>
> Maybe you tried to change something you didn't have access to.
>
> If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.

production.log

```
I, [2015-06-08T14:45:00.910686 #1912]  INFO -- : Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 13.17.28.5 at 2015-06-08 14:45:00 +0300
I, [2015-06-08T14:45:00.935492 #1912]  INFO -- : Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
I, [2015-06-08T14:45:00.997483 #1912]  INFO -- :   Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (19.4ms)
I, [2015-06-08T14:45:01.001749 #1912]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.7ms)
I, [2015-06-08T14:45:01.003426 #1912]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.9ms)
I, [2015-06-08T14:45:01.004884 #1912]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.6ms)
I, [2015-06-08T14:45:01.005711 #1912]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 70ms (Views: 30.7ms | ActiveRecord: 2.9ms)
I, [2015-06-08T14:45:02.245685 #1912]  INFO -- : Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 13.17.28.5 at 2015-06-08 14:45:02 +0300
I, [2015-06-08T14:45:02.248305 #1912]  INFO -- : Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
I, [2015-06-08T14:45:02.248514 #1912]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"âœ“", "authenticity_token"=>"B0NhIjKBWKJ3Rwjbenwc5jIQ9rAA8w/dLD4bAiBcy4w0/TV6W8PUzKGCHIfg4PY4J2eHhTMfzFYnYpYcSxFXGA==", "user"=>{"email"=>"your@email.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
W, [2015-06-08T14:45:02.250441 #1912]  WARN -- : Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
I, [2015-06-08T14:45:02.251337 #1912]  INFO -- : Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
F, [2015-06-08T14:45:02.255763 #1912] FATAL -- : 
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:181:in `handle_unverified_request'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:209:in `handle_unverified_request'
  devise (3.5.1) lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:251:in `handle_unverified_request'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:204:in `verify_authenticity_token'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:432:in `block in make_lambda'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:164:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:164:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `each'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
  actionview (4.2.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:49:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:819:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:649:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
  passenger (5.0.0.beta2) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:85:in `process_request'
  passenger (5.0.0.beta2) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:156:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
  passenger (5.0.0.beta2) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:111:in `main_loop'
  passenger (5.0.0.beta2) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:420:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
```

That's my default server for nginx

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name 123.123.123.123;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 256 4k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 240;
    }
}

server{
   listen 8080;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html/Logvs/public;
    server_name 123.123.123.123:8080;   
    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_app_env production;
}
```

The second one is what I am trying to access (port 8080).
Any ideas ? None of other SO answers worked.

Comment: Probably some different configuration of the web server or of the application server. Why do you use Passenger 5.0.0.beta2 instead of a stable version?

Comment: I have to complete an assignement and I am trying to make it work as it is. Is there something I could post in order to help find the root of the issue ?

Comment: posted my servers file also for nginx

Comment: You have just to ensure that nginx and Passenger respective versions and configurations are the same. Also, if the domain is the same (the IP if you access via IP) try to clear the cookies and the browser cache.

Comment: gem install passenger to 5.0.9 and the same thing continues. Also tried with tor browser which not stores cookies

Comment: You also need to ensure that your CSRF token is not cached.

Comment: @maxcal how? I cleared cache and cookies.

Comment: I'm talking about the Rails server side caching of rendered views. I once added the `csrf_meta_tags` inside a [Rails fragment cache](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#fragment-caching) (`<% cache do %>`) it was a particularily hard bug to squash  since it only  occured in production with a "warmed up" cache.

Comment: You might want to read the rest of the article on caching as well, if nginx is serving up a stale response you will get a mismatch between the CSRF token which the browser receives and what Rails expects.

Comment: I am doing a complete re-install for now as it doesn't seem normal.

Comment: Also, in `config/environments/production.rb` there should be a line regarding the nginx proxy header directive; is it enabled? It should be enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-rails-and-nginx-with-passenger-on-ubuntu I did a complete re-install of everything as it seemed that something was entirely wrong!

Comment: yes ! it was a misconfiguration or something... thanks for your time !